# Question about the existence of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals.

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I learned like the following:

For ***Riemann integrals***,
$$
\int_a^b fd\phi \quad \text{exists} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \sup_\Gamma L_\Gamma = \inf_\Gamma L_\Gamma
$$
where $\Gamma$ is a partition of $[a, b]$, $$\Gamma=\left\{x_i\right\}_{i=0}^m \quad \text{satisfying} \quad x_0=a < x_1 < \cdots <x_m=b$$

---

For ***Riemann-Stieltjes integrals***,
$$
\int_a^b fd\phi \quad \text{exists} \quad \nLeftrightarrow \quad \sup_\Gamma L_\Gamma = \inf_\Gamma L_\Gamma
$$
where $\Gamma$ is a partition of $[a, b]$, $$\Gamma=\left\{x_i\right\}_{i=0}^m \quad \text{satisfying} \quad x_0=a < x_1 < \cdots <x_m=b$$

---

My question is whether the following equation is true or not

For ***Riemann-Stieltjes integrals***,
$$
\int_a^b fd\phi \quad \text{exists} \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \lim_{|\Gamma|\to0}R_\Gamma\quad\text{exists}.
$$
where $R_\Gamma=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{m}f(\xi_i)[\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_{i-1})]$, $\xi_i\in[x_{i-1}, x_i]$.

Comment: The difference between Riemann and Riemann-Stieltjes integrals is that RS integrals let you specify a function to integrate against (i.e. "to weigh different parts of the space differently"). The $\phi$ function is analogous to measures in Lebesgue integrals.  Riemann integrals do not have a mechanism for $\phi,$ or rather it is baked into the definition of Riemann integration that $\phi(x)=x$. $${}$$ I don't think your middle section true. That is, I believe if that (the RS integral exists) iff ($\sup_\Gamma L_\Gamma = \inf_\Gamma L_\Gamma$). Can you provide a counterexample to this?

Comment: Further, ($\sup_\Gamma L_\Gamma = \inf_\Gamma L_\Gamma$) iff ($\lim_{|\Gamma|\to 0} L_\Gamma$ exists). The only possibility I see is if there is a distinction between your constructions $L_\Gamma$ and $R_\Gamma$.

Comment: The counterexample is: $a=-1, b=1, f(x)=0$ if $-1\le x\lt0$, $f(x)=1$ if $0\le x\le 1$, $\phi(x)=0$ if $-1\le x\le 0$, $\phi(x)=1$ if $0\lt x\le 1$.

Comment: $\sup_\Gamma L_\Gamma = \inf_\Gamma U_\Gamma = 1$, but neither $\lim_{|\Gamma|\to0}R_\Gamma$ nor $\lim_{|\Gamma|\to0}L_\Gamma$ exists.

Comment: What text are you learning this out of? In my construction, both those limits exist and equal 1 because as $|\Gamma|$ becomes small, any problems around 0 due to the left/right-discontinuousness go away.

Comment: My textbook is Measure and Integral: An Introduction to Real Analysis by Richard L. Wheeden and Antoni Zygmund. In addition, this book gave us the above counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

If $\{ x_i\}$ is taken to be: "any partition of $[a,b]$ of fineness less than or equal to $|\Gamma|$" then you have just written the definition of the Riemann-Stieltjes integral, so the answer to your question is yes.